# OSX: PPT to PDF

Tags: macos, pdf, microsoft-powerpoint

OSX 10.6 includes the ability to show a "preview" of PPT files by selecting a file in Finder and hitting Cmd-Y.

But in this preview, I cannot select text to copy and paste, and I cannot print or save in a different format.

Is there an app for OSX that simply converts PPTs to PDFs?

Comment: Office 2011 should provide you the ability to do exactly this.  Adobe Acrobat should also provide this ability ( even if you have to print the power point into a pdf file ).

Answer (score 0):

OS X builtin Preview is able to do that. Just open the file and select `File`->`Export` and select file format "pdf". You also could use the print dialog.

Comment: I just can't reach that File->Export you're describing when previewing a .ppt file

Comment: don't you have Microsoft Office installed? something else that makes it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Any app can print to PDF in the print dialog box.

If you don't have anything that opens this, try [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org) which can open PPT files, and can Export to PDF itself.